# Do I need a VPN to play AOE2 on the same LAN?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

Trying to setup AOE2 HD game in order to play over LAN. I have several laptops connected via wi-fi by using home router. I create game on first laptop and trying to connect from another one. Second laptop not finds first one hosted game.

I suppose since I play on LAN, I don't need any additional tools like VPN in order to connect PC's. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

I was trying to run this game on two vmware virtual machines hosted on same PC. These machines connects to each other fine fine.

Can I somehow tell AOE2 first machine IP dress in order to find served game?

How to connect client AOE2 to server one?

UPD

Firewall is off on both PC's and ping works fine in both ways.

UPD2

I have connected laptop and third desktop pc for battle in case both of them are on LAN wire connection. In case laptop is on wifi and destop on LAN wire connection fails even ping both ways runs fine. Why connection depends on wifi factor?

Comment: Have you made sure your firewall isn't blocking the connections? Can you ping your PC from your laptop?

Comment: This article (https://www.ageofempires.com/news/how-to-host-a-lan-game-in-aoe-ii-hd/) seems to suggest there is no direct connect option in the game, so I think you won't be able to directly specify the IP address... I'm not sure though, I don't own the game.

Comment: Firewalls are off on both PC's and I can ping both ways

Comment: Technically a VPN *is* a LAN, just a virtual one.. how would this be any different in the game? If a ping goes through it's something in the router or port settings.

Comment: Do all macinhes trying to connect have connection to the Internet?

Comment: yes, all machines has connection to internet. But do they need internet at all?

Answer (score 2):

Age of Empires 2 HD unfortunately doesn't really have a LAN setup.

The best thing you can do, is create a password-protected lobby and have the machines connect to that.

If you don't have HD and have day, Age of Kings, then you could also set up GameRanger and have everyone connect through that. Still needs Internet connection for all machines but it means you can play multilayer with all of the machines.

Comment: But I would like to play with persons in my LAN and don't want to go to the internet. And looks it is possible to manage without having any additional tools like GameRanger. Two AOE2 HD connection on LAN improves that.

Comment: @vico there probably are tools but nothing really inbuilt for it that I've ever seen. I mean, does it really need to be LAN if everyone has Internet?

Comment: All PC has internet because my home LAN is connected to internet. I'm trying to go simplest way without going to Internet since I don't know how to use GameRanger. I expect that all PC's on LAN will find AOE2 HD game creator that according to my understanding should send broadcast packets on LAN.

Comment: @vico my answer is the simplest way. It uses AoE2 HD default functionality .. it's just not technically LAN

Comment: @vico see herre: https://www.reddit.com/r/aoe2/comments/5twvkm/how_to_play_legit_aoe_ii_hd_over_lan_with_no/

Answer (score 0):

You can't LAN with Age of Empires 2 HD However you can use a tool [AoE2Tools](https://games.softpedia.com/get/Tools/AoE2Tools.shtml)  to convert your AoE2HD to AoC2 which are completely identical versions.

Luckily [here is a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Srhi14fjTkM) that walks you through it and it's a 5 min task.